# Searching gives repetitive Questions and Answers in single result page

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, search

I am searching on StackOverflow site for `SolrNet` based Question/Answers relating to `edismax`

But it is giving me same result in single result page but as different `Q:` and `A:` prefix and votes respective to those Question and Answer.

However I believe if the resulting item are point to same question (when you hover the links will show same question id in url) then it should be not shown twice or so Because this way I am being kept far far away from probable question or answer and page 1 is populated with duplicate.

Thus also the count of `20 results` (shown in screenshot) is very much incorrect.

---

**Search Url:** https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=solr+edismax+%5Bsolrnet%5D

---

**Search Text:** `solr edismax [solrnet]`

---

**Search Screenshot:**

[image: Repetitive search result screenshot]

Comment: This is by design for sure - they link to the specific question or answer in question. If you only want the _question_ to show, use `is:q`, for example http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=solr+edismax+%5Bsolrnet%5D+is%3Aq

Comment: You search for *posts*, where posts can be either questions or answers. No bug here.

Comment: Thanks for answer @m0sa. For #downvoter I tried to find the reason for this on meta site but was not to find that is why I posted question here and I think asking question about Stackoverflow on meta site is not wrongful act..

Comment: @HarshBaid: voting is different on meta - it can be used to indicate disagreement or opinions about the question. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta

Comment: Related: [Automatically append is:question to searches done from the upper right search box](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/174010)

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy I think you misunderstood.. Its saying **On posts tagged feature-request, voting indicates agreement or disagreement** and my question is not marked with [tag:feature-request] tag. I did not knew that it was [tag:bug] or [tag:status-bydesign] that's why I had posted this question..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to get only questions or answers use the `is:question` and `is:answer` options.

For example: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=solr+edismax+%5Bsolrnet%5D+is%3Aquestion